# Javascript filter deep array in array while maintaining original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, handlebars.js

I'm wanting to filter an array without changing the original array that I've sliced from. You can see that the first thing I do within the filterChange function is to splice from the original array. The original array still ends up changed as well and I don't understand why.

```
var MenuDisplayModule = (function ($, window, document, Handlebars) {

    var module = {};
    module.menuItems = [];
    module.init = function () {
        console.info('BreadcrumbDisplayModule Init');

    };
    module.template = function (array) {
        module.menuItems = array;
        var filteredMenuItems = array.slice(0);
        _template(filteredMenuItems);
    }
    module.filterChange = function (filterText) {

        var filteredMenuItems = module.menuItems.slice(0);

        filteredMenuItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
            var filteredItems = item.MenuItems.filter(function (el) {
                return (el.MenuText.includes(filterText));
            });
            filteredMenuItems[index].MenuItems = filteredItems;
        })
        _template(filteredMenuItems); 
    }
    function _template(filteredMenuItems) {
        var menu_items_source = $("#menu-items-template").html();
        var menu_items_template = Handlebars.compile(menu_items_source);
        $("#menu-items-placeholder").empty().html(menu_items_template({ menuItems: filteredMenuItems }));
    }
    return module;
}(window.jQuery, window, document, window.Handlebars));
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of where/how you use this module for testing purpose?

Comment: Without more information of the actual content of the arrays, the object's structure, it is hard to be conclusive, but `slice` only performs a shallow copy, and so the objects inside the array will be the same objects in any copy you make of that array. For instance, if you have DOM elements embedded in those arrays, you will never have copies of those. If they are placed in your document, they will actually *move*, not duplicate. Use the `clone` method on those DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the Array and create a new one with the filtered contents and leave the old one unchanged I suggest

```
newArray = oldArray.filter(function(item) { return item.wantThis === true; })
```

Now you have newArray consisting of only those Objects which have property

```
item.wantThis === true
```

In you example you are using `slice()` which in my experience looks very much like `splice()` (which will can mutate the Array).

I suggest you simply stick to using `filter()`.

But why are you making so many slice copies?

It would help if you posted an example of an Object in the array you receive.

Form looking at you example it seems that filteredItems is a private var to the previous ForEach loop, if you change that active part of your code to....

```
   module.filterChange = function (filterText) {

    var filteredMenuItems = module.menuItems.slice(0);

    var filteredItems; // declare the var outside of the .forEach

        filteredMenuItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
            filteredItems = item.MenuItems.filter(function (el) {
            return (el.MenuText.includes(filterText));
        });
        filteredMenuItems[index].MenuItems = filteredItems;
    })
    _template(filteredMenuItems); 
}
```

It might work.

The effect of your filteredItems is..

```
   filteredMenuItems.forEach(function(item) {
    item.MenuItems = item.MenuItems
                            .filter(function(el) { return (el.MenuText.includes(filterText)); });
    })
```

So your item.MenuItems will get smaller with each filter.

Comment: If you look halfway the OP's code, you'll see they already use this function. This is not the issue.

Comment: From MDN: The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified. Unless I don't understand what that means slice does not mutate the array you call it on.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears I didn't understand splice. Specifically the *shallow* aspect of it. Since I was wanting to filter on a sub array of the array I was trying to copy I ended up not getting an actual copy.

Instead of copying the array I'm creating a new array and pushing the results of the filter to it. Taking with it the un-filtered properties from the original array.

```
module.filterChange = function (filterText) {
    var filteredMenuItems = [];
    module.menuItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
        var filteredItems = item.MenuItems.filter(function (el) {
            return (el.MenuText.includes(filterText));
        });
        filteredMenuItems.push({
            HeaderText: item.HeaderText,
            ID: item.ID,
            MenuItems: filteredItems
        })
    })
    _templateOnChange(filteredMenuItems); 
}
```